# IG credibility finding requirements

Tags: united-states, justice-department

As most know an Inspector General (IG) must deem a complaint credible, and the [Intelligence Community IG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspector_General_of_the_Intelligence_Community) deemed the Whistleblower complaint in [affair Ukraine](https://thefederalist.com/tag/ukraine/) credible.  But it appears the IG [didn't even review the phone call transcript](https://thefederalist.com/2019/10/02/ic-inspector-general-didnt-review-ukraine-call-before-forwarding-whistleblower-complaint/). Are there Departmental procedures for evaluating credibility, and if so what are they?

Comment: "Are the Departmental procedures for evaluating credibility, and if so what are they?", is that a question? Or did youmean to say "Are there...."

Comment: This question seems to be phrased rather hastily based on the recent whistle blower. I think the general question is interesting, but it would be better if it's phrased around the question, not around recent events. Please proofread your question before posting and make sure the title and body clearly present the question. Now it seems just as much a promotion of the Federalist as a attempt at learning about departmental policy.

Comment: Contast "Did the ICIG determine the complaint to be credible?" with "Why did the ICIG determine the complaint credible".  The first q. asks for a fact. Unless and until the ICIG publishes or announces the reasons for his finding of credible, the "Why" question cannot be answered without speculation.  However, on review of your question I don't see the word "why" - so there seems to be no reason for your "but not why" comment.

Comment: @BobE: I vaguely recall that  Maguire said that the ICIG corroborated the complaint with other testimony before coming to that conclusion, i.e. it seems he "asked around".

Comment: Why has this been closed? How is "Are there Departmental procedures for evaluating credibility, and if so what are they?" pushing an agenda if this hubbub is such a pressing issue?

Comment: @BobE they are both facts, and here I am not asking why but how

Comment: Currently displayed comments seem to refer to comments that have been deleted, and therefore make no sense. WTBS, I'm looking for your Q of "How..."

Answer (score 1):

> Are there Departmental procedures for evaluating credibility, and if so what are they?

The requirement, with respect to a whistleblower complaints of "urgent concern", is that "the Inspector General shall determine whether the complaint or **information appears credible**." *See* 50 U.S. Code § 3033 (k)(5)(B).<sup>1</sup> [Emphasis added.]

The Director of National Intelligence (DNI), the parent for the Inspector General of the Intelligence Community, published the following definition.

> **Credible Information.** Information disclosed or obtained by an investigator that, considering the source and nature of the information and the totality of the circumstances, is sufficiently believable to lead a trained investigator to presume that the fact or facts in question are true. (DoDI 5505.7, 7 Jan 2003) <sup>2</sup>

There is a similarity between "appears" (seem; give the impression of being) and "presume" (suppose that something is the case on the basis of probability). Neither of these words suggest a requirement to investigate all possible evidence (or facts) to reach a "determination" (the resolving of a question by argument or reasoning) of "appearance" or "presumption".

IG investigations, not of "urgent concern", deal with more information and facts, rather than "appearance", and have much longer time frames to reach their conclusions.

---

<sup>1</sup> [50 U.S. Code § 3033.Inspector General of the Intelligence Community](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/50/3033).

<sup>2</sup> [Terms & Definitions of Interest for DOD Counterintelligence Professionals](https://www.dni.gov/files/NCSC/documents/ci/CI_Glossary.pdf).